# Why when I ping www.ebay.com, it request this host e9428.b.akamaiedge.net.0.1.cn.akamaiedge.net, not www.ebay.com?

Tags: networking, dns, ping, cdn

I think ping will send packet to www.ebay.com, but it request a cdn. Here is the response detail:
[ping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bzvH.png)

Answer (score 1):

ebay.com is an alias that routes to a server that serves up ebay in your area. Checkout nwtools.com enter a domian in the search box and get the details on domains. So if I ping ebay I get a different server e9428.b.akamaiedge.net

Net tools shows the following info and more.

```
172.233.91.10 is from United States (US) in region North America
Input: www.ebay.com
canonical name: e9428.b.akamaiedge.net
aliases:
www.ebay.com
www-us.g.ebay.com
slot9428.ebay.com.edgekey.net
```

Answer (score 1):

A check of eBay's DNS records shows that www.ebay.com is a CNAME record which resolves to e9428.b.akamaiedge.net. eBay like many large websites running at the same scale use CDN providers to deploy the website as close to the end user as possible which is what the akamaiedge network does.

The full DNS query for www.ebay.com is

```
www.ebay.com. 136 IN CNAME www-us.g.ebay.com.
www-us.g.ebay.com. 16 IN CNAME slot9428.ebay.com.edgekey.net.
slot9428.ebay.com.edgekey.net. 9713 IN CNAME e9428.b.akamaiedge.net.
e9428.b.akamaiedge.net. 11 IN A 23.198.167.10
```

What this effectively means is that www.ebay.com bounces through 3 CNAME records and eventually resolves to e9428.b.akamaiedge.net which is an endpoint on the Akamai Edge network and that is where you go to to access the www.ebay.com website.